# Call manually PlayFramework custom error page

Tags: java, scala, playframework, playframework-2.4

I implemented custom pages in PlayFramework just like documentation says: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaErrorHandling

I've added reference to ErrorHandler in application.conf

```
play.http.errorHandler = "com.company.ErrorHandler"
```

and I've implemented ErrorHandler itself:

```
public class ErrorHandler extends DefaultHttpErrorHandler {

    @Inject
    public ErrorHandler(Configuration configuration, Environment environment, OptionalSourceMapper sourceMapper, Provider<Router> routes) {
        super(configuration, environment, sourceMapper, routes);
    }

    @Override
    public F.Promise<Result> onClientError(Http.RequestHeader requestHeader, int errorCode, String message) {
        Logger.debug("Error: onClientError : " + errorCode + ", message: " + message);
        return super.onClientError(requestHeader, errorCode, message);
    }

    @Override
    public F.Promise<Result> onServerError(Http.RequestHeader request, Throwable exception) {
        Logger.debug("Error: onServerError general");
        return F.Promise.pure(redirect(com.company.routes.ErrorController.serverErrorPage()));
    }

    @Override
    protected F.Promise<Result> onBadRequest(Http.RequestHeader request, String message) {
        Logger.debug("Error: onBadRequest, message: " + message);
        return F.Promise.pure(redirect(com.company.routes.ErrorController.badRequestPage()));
    }

    @Override
    protected F.Promise<Result> onForbidden(Http.RequestHeader request, String message) {
        Logger.debug("Error: onForbidden, message: " + message);
        return F.Promise.pure(redirect(com.company.routes.ErrorController.forbiddenPage()));
    }

    @Override
    protected F.Promise<Result> onNotFound(Http.RequestHeader request, String message) {
        Logger.debug("Error: onNotFound, message: " + message);
        return F.Promise.pure(redirect(com.company.routes.ErrorController.notFoundPage()));
    }

    @Override
    protected F.Promise<Result> onOtherClientError(Http.RequestHeader request, int statusCode, String message) {
        Logger.debug("Error: onOtherClientError, message: " + message);
        return F.Promise.pure(redirect(com.company.routes.ErrorController.errorDefaultPage()));
    }
}
```

Custom pages works great when error it thrown by framework itself.

Although I have a problem with redirecting to error pages from controller. When I call end point:

```
public Result contact() {
    return Results.forbidden("Forbidden");
}
```

The error page from ErrorHander isn't shown. I only see text "Forbidden".

How can I show my custom error page without explicitly redirecting to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to call client error directly by injecting it to desired element. I ended up with following solution (Play Framework 2.5):

```
public class ErrorHandler extends DefaultHttpErrorHandler {

    private ErrorController errorController;

    @Inject
    public ErrorHandler(Configuration configuration,
                        Environment environment,
                        OptionalSourceMapper sourceMapper,
                        Provider<Router> routes,
                        ErrorController errorController) {
        super(configuration, environment, sourceMapper, routes);

        this.errorController = errorController;
    }

    @Override
    public CompletionStage<Result> onServerError(Http.RequestHeader request, Throwable exception) {
        Logger.debug("Error: onServerError general");
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(this.errorController.serverErrorPage());
    }

    @Override
    protected CompletionStage<Result> onBadRequest(Http.RequestHeader request, String message) {
        Logger.debug("Error: onBadRequest, message: " + message);
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(this.errorController.badRequestPage());
    }

    @Override
    protected CompletionStage<Result> onForbidden(Http.RequestHeader request, String message) {
        Logger.debug("Error: onForbidden, message: " + message);
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(this.errorController.forbiddenPage());
    }

    @Override
    protected CompletionStage<Result> onNotFound(Http.RequestHeader request, String message) {
        Logger.debug("Error: onNotFound, message: " + message);
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(this.errorController.notFoundPage());
    }

    @Override
    protected CompletionStage<Result> onOtherClientError(Http.RequestHeader request, int statusCode, String message) {
        Logger.debug("Error: onOtherClientError, message: " + message);
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(this.errorController.errorDefaultPage());
    }
}
```

Then I can call it like:

```
class SomeElement  {

    private final DefaultHttpErrorHandler errorHandler;

    @Inject
    public SomeElement(DefaultHttpErrorHandler errorHandler) {
        this.errorHandler = errorHandler;
    }

    public CompletionStage<Result> onAuthFailure(final Http.Context context,
                                                 final Optional<String> content) {
        return this.errorHandler.onClientError(context.request(), Http.Status.FORBIDDEN, "You don't have required permissions.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and I solved it with overriding onClientError and switch into the different HTTP status codes:

```
public class ErrorHandler extends DefaultHttpErrorHandler {

  @Inject
  public ErrorHandler(Configuration configuration, Environment environment,
        OptionalSourceMapper sourceMapper, Provider<Router> routes) {
      super(configuration, environment, sourceMapper, routes);
  }

  @Override
  public Promise<Result> onClientError(RequestHeader request, int statusCode,
        String message) {
    switch (statusCode) {
    case Http.Status.BAD_REQUEST:
        Logger.info(CLASS_NAME + ".onBadRequest: " + message);
        return Promise.<Result> pure(
                Results.badRequest(views.html.error.render("Bad request")));
    case Http.Status.NOT_FOUND:
        Logger.info(CLASS_NAME + ".onNotFound: Requested page \""
                + request.uri() + "\" couldn't be found.");
        return Promise.<Result> pure(
                Results.notFound(views.html.error.render("Requested page \""
                        + request.uri() + "\" couldn't be found.")));
    case Http.Status.FORBIDDEN:
        Logger.info(CLASS_NAME + ".onForbidden: " + message);
        return Promise.<Result> pure(Results
                .forbidden("You're not allowed to access this resource."));
    default:
        Logger.info(CLASS_NAME + ".onClientError: HTTP status code "
                + statusCode + ", " + message);
        return Promise.<Result> pure(Results.status(statusCode,
                views.html.error.render("Internal server error")));
    }
  }

  @Override
  public Promise<Result> onServerError(RequestHeader request,
        Throwable exception) {
    Logger.info(CLASS_NAME + ".onServerError: Internal server error",
            exception);
    return Promise.<Result> pure(Results.internalServerError(
            views.html.error.render("Internal server error")));
  }

}
```

Maybe it's even an error in Play's documentation? At least in `HttpErrorHandler` interface it does not talk about other methods than `onServerError` or `onClientError` (https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.0/api/java/play/http/HttpErrorHandler.html).

Comment: That's a good point. But if you check underlying implementation of DefaultHttpErrorHandler, then you will notice that it's already redirecting calls in onClientError to other methods like for e.g. onBadRequest, onForbidden.

My problem is that despite returning Results. forbidden(). The request is not being caught by custom ErrorHandler.

Comment: You seem to be right. Maybe it works in Play 2.5 - they changed a lot in DefaultHttpErrorHandler compared to 2.4.